# Caching for each user

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I don't fully understand how should I approach caching data for each specific user with symfony framework. I'm creating a quiz app, so each user has its own quiz, each quiz has its own category, each category has its own questions. I don't want user to fetch his data from database everytime he loads a website, I want him to store his quiz data and validate if it's still same as in DB (if he modified from another computer). I tried to code it by myself but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
#[Route('/quiz', name: 'app_quiz')]
    public function index(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
    {

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setEtag(md5($response->getContent()));


        if ($response->isNotModified($request)) {
            return $response;
        }
        
        // rendered all quizes
        $quizes = $this->getUser()->getQuiz();

        // form to add quiz
        $quiz = new Quiz();
        $quiz->setOwner($this->getUser());
        $form = $this->createForm(QuizType::class, $quiz);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($form->getData());
            $em->flush();
        }
        

        $this->render('quiz/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'quizes' => $quizes,
        ], $response);

        return $response;


    }
```

Comment: You either have to save it on a database on the server or in a cookie at the browser.

Comment: *"I don't want user to fetch his data from database everytime he loads a website"*, why? This is normal and Doctrine will do it's thing under the hood and cache its results if need be.

Comment: so it's not recommended to cache data fetched directly from the database?